# How to select unchecked checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery UI tabs. I have 2 tabs with id `#tab1` & `#tab2` respectively. Both tab

contains *2 checkbox (total 4)*. And currently all are `unchecked`. Now i wrote this jquery code :

```
  $("#tab2").find("input:not(:checked)").each(function () { alert("1"); });
```

My problem is that, the alert *come 4 times*, but it should *come 2 times*. Whats the problem here?

**EDIT**

```
       <div class="dialog">
            <div id="tab">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#tab1">A</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab2">B</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="tab1">
                        <input type="checkbox" />
                        <input type="checkbox" />
                </div>
                <div id="tab2">
                        <input type="checkbox" />
                        <input type="checkbox" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you show to us your html?

Comment: or post a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: This is correct behavior. Do you just want the unchecked checkboxes of the active (current) tab?

Comment: @BenediktOlek How this behavior is correct , i am finding the unchecked check-boxes in `tab2`, which is 2, so why the alert show me 4 times ?

Comment: Does the tab contain other input types? Try `:checkbox:not(:checked)` instead.

Comment: @JCN: Why avoid post a piece of your code ?

Comment: @BenediktOlek `.find()` includes children (children are **direct descendants**), `.children()` **only** does children.

Comment: Strange... it works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/antyrat/tHGNF/

Comment: Right, my guess was his markup was diffrent. Now - this snipped should work fine - and it does for me! http://jsfiddle.net/nkbLZ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**check this fiddle . it is working fine for me..**

http://jsfiddle.net/kabichill/6XmYn/